# what are hyperbranched amplicons in DNA sequencing?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing

I am reading an article about single-cell sequencing:
http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nbt.2720.html

And came across the concept of "hyperbranched amplicons". I googled for it but don't get much luck. The best I could find is it mentioned in another single-cell sequencing method here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_displacement_amplification

Can someone give me a definition for it?